# jQuery: testing for existence of something

Tags: jquery

Newbie alert...

I'm trying to make an educational that uses different audio players (with different ids) depending on the browser.  In some cases, the div ids will be #f-FIVE, for example, or, in other cases just #FIVE.  This is not something I have a lot of control over due to the audio players.

Using jQuery, I want to use the div ids to test for which audio player is being used.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eft84/15/, I am trying (unsuccessfully) to fade out an element using an if then structure if #f-FIVE exists.  Would you be kind enough to help me spot my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/SySRb/

```
$('#f-FIVE').length
```

Will be 1 or more if there is a match (Should be exactly one since it's an id selector). If there is no match it will be 0 and evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can check if the result of a selector is empty like this:

```
if ($("#f-FIVE").length) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. PaulPRo answered first so I have to give him accepted answer.